VisualSVN Branch and Merge - What did I do wrong?
I'm using VisualSVN within Visual Studio and TortoiseSVN where needed.
I needed to create a branch in my repository to develop a beta version of our software with some new features. The beta branch development took a few weeks, and there were a number of bug fixes and enhancements on the trunk during that time. Each time there was a revision of the trunk, I merged those changes into the branch, thinking that it would make merging the branch back to the trunk easier at the end. I didn't encounter any issues with the merges from trunk to branch.
When I finished with the branch and merged my changes back to the trunk, I had many conflicts. Some were code conflicts, which made sense because they dealt with changes that I had made in the branch. But I also had a number of tree conflicts. When I tried to resolve the tree conflicts, I got a lot of error messages saying something like "an attempt was made to merge changes into a file that does not exist in the working copy". Well, no kidding! I'm trying to merge those changes back into the working copy.
Here's how I attempted the failed merge:

Use VisualSVN "Switch" to switch to the trunk.
Use VisualSVN "Merge" to merge changes from the beta branch. I had already committed all changes to the branch and I had no pending changes in the trunk.

At the end of the day, I had to check out a fresh copy of the beta branch and manually merge all of the tree-conflicted files back into the trunk.
Was my mistake merging all the changes from trunk to the branch, and then trying to merge that branch back into the trunk? How would something like this normally be handled?
